# Using mxnet pre-trained image classification model in R

Tags: r, mxnet

Running the tutorial at the link below, I get the error below when I get to the step below. No errors before this point.

http://mxnet.io/tutorials/r/classifyRealImageWithPretrainedModel.html

> prob <- predict(model, X=normed)
>   [19:01:35] D:\chhong\mxnet\dmlc-core\include\dmlc/logging.h:235: [19:01:35] d:\chhong\mxnet\src\operator./concat-inl.h:152: Check failed: (dshape[j]) == (tmp[j]) Incorrect shape[2]: (1,320,15,15). (first input shape: (1,576,14,14))
>   Error: InferShape Error in ch_concat_3c_chconcat: [19:01:35] d:\chhong\mxnet\src\operator./concat-inl.h:152: Check failed: (dshape[j]) == (tmp[j]) Incorrect shape[2]: (1,320,15,15). (first input shape: (1,576,14,14))

Comment: To ask a troubleshooting question you need to provide the code and data to reproduce your problem within the question itself

Comment: I am the maintainer for the mxnet R package. First, I suggest you open issues on github. Second, the reason for your problem is that the Windows package is too old. It hasn't been updated for quite a while because I don't have access to any Windows machine now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the tutorial got fixed or one of the components got fixed but this tutorial executes without errors when testing today on Mac

Comment: As mentioned in [Qiang's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132794/using-mxnet-pre-trained-image-classification-model-in-r/49060756#comment69513882_41132794), the problem appears on WINDOWS machines.

Answer (score 0):

I have run the tutorial on my Windows Server R2 2012 machine with mxnet version 0.10.1 and R version 3.4.3.

It runs okay, and the only thing that went wrong is that on the time I run it at the first time `require(mxnet)` package returned me:

```
> require(mxnet)
Loading required package: mxnet
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mxnet’:
 object ‘set_global_graph_attrs’ is not exported by 'namespace:DiagrammeR'
```

I had to install and load DiagrammeR manually to make sure it starts. Here is the code to do so:

```
# Make sure you have devtools installed already
require(devtools)
install_version("DiagrammeR", version = "0.9.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
require(DiagrammeR)
```

After that I run the tutorial again and it worked fine.